# Swift Cocoa App The application can't be opened

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've developed a `macOS` app written with Swift. For testing I archived then `Distribute` for AppStore and export it. The exported folder includes `MyApp.pkg` file then I zipped `.pkg` file and send it to testers. But when app is installed and they try to open it there is an error with `The application can't be opened`.

In my current development laptop, it works but in testers not working. I try to execute it with

`chmod +x "/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp"` but there is no response.

How can I solve the problem for working it in testers laptops.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app archived and then distributed for the App Store cannot be sent directly to testers. It must be downloaded from the App Store. A pkg file is useless to individuals. You need to distribute for people! Send them  an app, not a pkg.

Comment: Hey @matt, thanks for answer, there's a situation like this; I integrate Apple Sign In then firstly I export the app with `Development` from the Àrchive`. `.app` not worked the apple sign in when the others test it so I decided to try it with `App Store` .pkg file.

Comment: Fine but that’s not the question you asked.

Comment: yeah, absolutely but the answer is correct for the wrong asked question. Thanks for it.